# Bibliography typesetting error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, springernature, stack

I am using a custom nature.bst file for writing a Springer journal and getting the above Error for the references.

```
> %%\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals
%%\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style
%%documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style 
%%\documentclass[sn-chicago]{sn-jnl}% Chicago-based Humanities Reference Style
%%\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}% Default
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{sn-nature.bst}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl
\end{document}"
```

here are the entries in the bibliography file

```
     @article{vajpayee2023medical,
        title={Medical image fusion by adaptive Gaussian PCNN and improved Roberts operator},
        author={Vajpayee, Pravesh and Panigrahy, Chinmaya and Kumar, Anil},
        journal={Signal, Image and Video Processing},
        pages={1--9},
        year={2023},
        publisher={Springer}}
    @inproceedings{narmadha2022detection,
        title={Detection of Human Brain Tumor by Medical Image Processing and PCA Based Image Fusion},
        author={Narmadha, M and Arthi, L and Narmatha, T},
        booktitle={2022 IEEE 2nd International Conference on Mobile Networks and Wireless Communications (ICMNWC)},
        pages={1--5},
        year={2022},
        organization={IEEE}
    }
    @article{zuo2017airborne,
        title={Airborne infrared and visible image fusion combined with region segmentation},
        author={Zuo, Yujia and Liu, Jinghong and Bai, Guanbing and Wang, Xuan and Sun, Mingchao},
        journal={Sensors},
        volume={17},
        number={5},
        pages={1127},
        year={2017},
        publisher={MDPI}
    }
    
    @article{muller2009cognitively,
        title={Cognitively-engineered multisensor image fusion for military applications},
        author={Muller, Amanda C and Narayanan, S},
        journal={Information Fusion},
        volume={10},
        number={2},
        pages={137--149},
        year={2009},
        publisher={Elsevier}
    }
@inproceedings{ram2017deepfuse,
    title={Deepfuse: A deep unsupervised approach for exposure fusion with extreme exposure image pairs},
    author={Ram Prabhakar, K and Sai Srikar, V and Venkatesh Babu, R},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE international conference on computer vision},
    pages={4714--4722},
    year={2017}
}

@inproceedings{li2018infrared,
    title={Infrared and visible image fusion using a deep learning framework},
    author={Li, Hui and Wu, Xiao-Jun and Kittler, Josef},
    booktitle={2018 24th international conference on pattern recognition (ICPR)},
    pages={2705--2710},
    year={2018},
    organization={IEEE}
}
```

The references are shown in the bibliography but I want to resolve the following warning. I noticed the error is only generated for the bibtex with @inproceedings. What can be the alternatives?

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022) 
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003 
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux 
The style file: sn-nature.bst.bst 
Database file #1: sn-bibliography.bib 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry narmadha2022detection while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry liu2022target while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry ram2017deepfuse while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry li2018infrared while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry dutta2023seeing while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry xue2022object while executing---line 1702 of file sn-nature.bst.bst 
Warning--empty journal in Toet2022
```

[sn-nature.bst](https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/nature.bst)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: You should change `\bibliographystyle{sn-nature.bst}` to `\bibliographystyle{sn-nature}`, i.e., omit the filename extension. And, it look like the `Toet2022` is missing the `journal` field. (Or should the entry maybe not be of type `@article`?)

Comment: @Mico   @article{Toet2022,
 author = "Alexander Toet",
 title = "{TNO Image Fusion Dataset}",
 year = "2022",
 month = "10",
 url = "https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/TNO_Image_Fusion_Dataset/1008029",
 doi = "10.6084/m9.figshare.1008029.v2"
}

Comment: @Mico The error continues to show up still.

Comment: It’s wrong to use the `@article` entry type for the `Toet2022` entry. Try the `@misc` entry type instead.

Comment: Thank you. It is resolved. But can you share what to do with the @inproceedings bibtex. That error is still showing.

Comment: BibTeX error and warning messages are notoriously difficult to parse. To make some headway, I would start by backfilling some of the missing fields, in particular, the `editor` field. I noticed that every single entry of type `@inproceedings` is missing the `editor` field.

Comment: @Mico ok thanks. I will check